# mysql query doesn't work together with cross domain in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, cross-domain

my problem is the following... 
I made some php code that reads records from a mysql database:

```
$host = $_SESSION['host'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$db = $_SESSION['db'];

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         ...
    }
}
```

my html:

```
<button onclick="list">submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
var thisHost = "host.php";
function list() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: thisHost,
        data: "list=true",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $("#output").html(data);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.warn(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

as far as that everything is working fine. However now i want to call the php code from another host. Therefor the html file is on the other host (localhost:81) and the php file stays on the old host (localhost:80).

now I noticed that i need a something to cross the domain because ajax doesn't seem to work with other hosts. So all i did was adding these lines to the php code right at the beginning:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

and change the value of the thisHost var in javascript to

```
"http://localhost:80/host.php"
```

after that the ajax part works again and the php response. However every time i want to make a query by doing something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
```

i will get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in C:\path\to\host.php:71 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\path\to\host.php on line 71

i'm pretty sure that the query is correct. So what do i need to change?

Comment: You didn't check for errors when creating your connection, it's `null`. JavaScript code here is completely irrelevant.

Comment: i got it. The reason for the problem was the session i used to stay connected. I didn't check that the session doesn't work if i have different hosts :/ Thank you!

Comment: Storing credentials in the `$_SESSION` like that is asking for trouble. Hopefully there's a better way.

Comment: @stackEr as tadman stated, you don't want creds in your $_SESSION variable. Put those in a file unaccessible to public and refer to it when you need a connection. If you can't I'd like to know when your site is up because I need to practice my hacking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a method on an invalid handle will produce errors like this. Always check that your connection request succeeded and handle any errors that could have occurred.

Turning on `mysqli` exceptions makes these things a lot harder to ignore.